# Display list of acceptable values for parameter of a function in code time

Tags: vb.net

It is clear to every VB.NET developer that when try to code in VS, the intellisense offers values for parameters of .NET functions; But now the question is that how to define a function that when coding, itself helps us to choose acceptable value for parameter of function?

an image that maybe help: 
[image: Image of MsgBoxStyle Enumerations being shown by intellisense]

Comment: Please describe _... the intellisense offers values for parameters of .NET functions;_

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add description to functions and function parameters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5717359/how-to-add-description-to-functions-and-function-parameters)

Comment: an image that maybe help: [link](http://oi60.tinypic.com/91cns8.jpg)

Comment: Those are [Enums](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8h84wky1.aspx)

Comment: that question is about descriptions, but my purpose is list of acceptable value for a parameter

Comment: This only makes sense in the case of the parameter being an enum. What would  you want to see if the parameter were an integer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While Enums offer that behaviour "natively" it also exists for other non-Enum type for example System.Drawing.Color or System.Drawing.Brush which when dotted into presents a similar list of "harcoded values". And this behaviour is also possible on custom types (at least in VB.Net ; unless there was changes that's not available in C#).

How does this work ? it's with the use of an undocumented XML documentation tag namely *completionlist* in which you reference a type, either the same (as for Color) or another (as for Brush which references Brushes). And inside this type **ALL** public `static`/`Shared` fields and properties will be in the completion list (even those which aren't of the referencing type)

So for example (really contrived) you could have something like this :

```
''' <completionlist cref="FamousPeople"/>
Class People
    ' ...
End Class

NotInheritable Class FamousPeople
    Public Shared ReadOnly Sehnsucht As New People("Sehnsucht") ' Why not ?
    Shared ReadOnly Property JohnSkeet As New People("John Skeet")
    Shared ReadOnly Property EricLippert As New People("Eric Lippert")
    Shared ReadOnly Property MarcGravell As New People("Marc Gravell")
End Class
```

(I could have put them inside People directly if I wanted)

And then when you have to supply a value of type People the Intellisense shows you the "list" defined (whith the choice to create one not listed if you wish of course)

Answer (score 2):

You can add a description to your methods, properties and classes by adding 3 single quotes (`'''`) before each of them. This will create some documentation comments like:

```
''' <summary>
''' Description sumary for the method
''' </summary>
''' <param name="param1">param 1 description.</param>
''' <param name="param2">param 2 description.</param>
''' <returns>return description</returns>
Public Function FunctionName(param1 As String, param2 As int) As String
   ' ...
End Function
```

Don't be afraid of remembering all of this XML like syntax. VS will generate it for you. You just have to insert your info.

**Tip:**

If you have some range of values for a parameter, it may be better to use an `Enum` (http://www.dotnetperls.com/enum-vbnet)

```
Enum AnimalType
    None = 0
    Cat = 1
    Dog = 2
End Enum

Sub FeedAnimal(animalType As AnimalType)
    If animalType = AnimalType.Cat Then
        ' ...
    End If
End Sub
```

**Tip 2:**

If your parameters NEED to be strings you can create a class with some constants to help with this or implemente some shared properties to use instances:

```
''' <completionlist cref="AnimalType"/>
Class AnimalType
    Private Name As String

    Public Shared ReadOnly Cat As AnimalType = New AnimalType("Cat")
    Public Shared ReadOnly Dog As AnimalType = New AnimalType("Dog")

    Private Sub New(Name as String)
        Me.Name = Name 
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
        Return Me.Name 
    End Function
End Class
```

Comment: thanks, your answer is helpful and my purpose was achieved, but `Enum` is num! (i.e. `Integer`) now what can we do for string?

Comment: Take a look at my Tip 2.